# why does this loop only work once

Tags: javascript

I can't work out why this only loops through the array once in JavaScript. It should log the second nested array as well.

JSFiddle below and code below;

http://jsfiddle.net/HJfbT/

```
b = [["one", "is"],
 ["two", "is"]];

for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < b[x].length; x++) {
        console.log(b[i][x]);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have a typo:

```
// --- should be i ---v
for (var x = 0; x < b[x].length; x++) {
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/HJfbT/1/

Comment: @VisionN is it ok to give jsfiddle links in answers?, perhaps the link is broken...?

Comment: what if the link is broken in future?

Comment: @pinkpanther I never provide **demo**-only answers. As you can see, the **demo** is appended to the real answer body, just in order to present the working case for the OP. If the link is broken, it is still understandable what was wrong with the initial snippet.

Comment: ah ok, but what I don't understand is why does it work with the i variable - b[i].length? And not work with the x variable?- b[X].length?

Comment: @user1831677 That's all going to the nested loops. `i` is a counter of *'rows'*, while `x` is a counter of *'columns'*. Otherwise you will iterate by diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Use `b[i].length` in the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think is because the inner loop have the running condition with an error.

Is:

```
for (var x = 0; x < b[x].length; x++)
```

but must be:

```
for (var x = 0; x < b[i].length; x++)
```